# How to get data from a Card to update a Table in Oracle APEX?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

I have a cards region on my apex application where I use a query to get all the restaurants in a table and show then in each card. My problem is that when the user clicks on the card, I want it to update a temporary table that will get the info of that restaurant, then another action will redirect then to a restaurant detailed page where it will show the logo, name and description of the selected card using the temporary table. I'm open to suggestions and new ideas of this method. Thanks!

I tried using the normal SQL update calling the columns of the main table but it didn't work out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like an overly complex approach from someone who is new to Oracle APEX (No offense !). Typically a card links to a detail form where a user can update the record based on the primary key value that is passed in the link. That "form" can be replaced with a display only page.

You state *i want it to update a temporary table that will get the info of that restaurant, then another action will redirect then to a restaurante detailed page where it will show the logo, name and description of the selected card using the temporary table*

As I understand it, the user will click on the card and be redirected to a page that has the restaurant info.

So... create that page (lets call it page 1) and with a page item P1_RESTAURANT_ID to hold the primary key of the restaurant. In a before rendering process, query the data you need to render the restaurant info. In page regions, render whatever you need. In the card create a link to page 1 passing the restaurant_id value to P1_RESTAURANT_ID

There should be no temporary table involved in the entire process.

To understand this process, as a test, I suggest you use the create page wizard to generate an interactive report and form on your restaurant table. Then add a cards region to the report page to point to the form, then update the form to display exactly what you want.

Comment: It worked, i created a full card action where he stores the id in the hidden page item and redirects to the page. Thanks for the help!